# RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile how get notification on complete (NOT ALERT MESSAGE)

Tags: react-native, notifications

How to notifiy the user on success the file write.

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, Base64Code[1], 'base64')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res > 0) {
                alert('download_success');
            } else {
                alert('download_failed');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a local notification with [react-native-push-notification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification)

Here's how you can do it:

first of all, import the library

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification'
```

and then, the function itself:

```js
RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, Base64Code[1], 'base64')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res > 0) {
                PushNotification.localNotification({
                    id: '69',
                    ticker: "Download sucess!",
                    autoCancel: true,
                    vibrate: true,
                    vibration: 300,
                    ongoing: false, 
                    priority: "high",
                    visibility: "private",
                    importance: "high", 
                    title: "My app name",
                    message: "Your file has now ben saved!"
                });
            } else {
                PushNotification.localNotification({
                    id: '69',
                    ticker: "Download error!",
                    autoCancel: true,
                    vibrate: true,
                    vibration: 300,
                    ongoing: false, 
                    priority: "high",
                    visibility: "private",
                    importance: "high", 
                    title: "My app name",
                    message: "Errors ocurred while saving the file!"
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            RNFetchBlob.fs
            .writeFile(pathToWrite, data, 'utf8')
            .then(() => {
              RNFetchBlob.android.addCompleteDownload({
                title: 'data.pdf',
                description: 'Download complete',
                mime: 'application/pdf',
                path: pathToWrite,
                showNotification: true,
              });

              console.log(`wrote file ${pathToWrite}`);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```